# There is no real 'prepared statement' in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, prepared-statement

When we use ActiveRecord, we can use:

```
User.find(:first, :conditions=>["name=?", name])
```

It looks like ActiveRecord are using 'prepared statement', but after looking into the code, I found ActiveRecord just use `String.dup` and `connection.quote()` to adjust the content to build a sql, not like Java.

So, there is no real `prepared statment` in raiils? And why rails doesn't provide it?

Comment: What database platform are you using? Is there an example of a use case where you believe a prepared statement is necessary?

Comment: I'm asking this because I was a Java developer. When I developed in Java, almost all the time I used `prepared statement`, so I feel a little strange that I can't find prepared statement in rails.

Comment: Another thing, I wanted to insert some data to database, these data are hash, key is the column name, value is the column content. I wanted to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection directly, and found the `execute` method only accept a `string`. That I have to build the sql manually. But if there is prepared statement, that it will be simpler.

Comment: (1) Java != Ruby, but I guess you already spotted that :) (2) If you have a table defined to take that data, AR does that really easily with the [#create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001783) method, which explicitly takes a hash as you describe. Or an array of hashes, for multiple rows, in fact. It's a pretty mature framework - if something's really useful (within the technical context) then it's almost certainly there. Somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by prepared statement you mean a piece of SQL that is held in a compiled form for more efficient execution, then you're correct: it's not something implemented in Rails. There are several reasons for this:

1. Rails is the web framework - it doesn't know or care about databases. By default, Rails uses

   - ActiveRecord for object-relational mapping. You can change this if you want to - it doesn't have to be a RDBMS even.
   - ActiveRecord doesn't know about specific database platforms. For that it relies on "adapters", which translate AR's requirements into platform-specific SQL.
   - Some RDBMSs that have AR adapters support prepared statements (or equivalent) but others don't.

Comment: Interesting. Where would I find out which adapters support prepared statements?

Comment: I suggest going to the source; there are only 3 AR adapters (mysql, postgresql and sqlite): http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/1c11437a32a973fa9b521c32caa7256f9772acd7/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters

Comment: @egarcia - Not at all! I use Oracle in production and have used SQL Server in the past. Both have AR adapters, they just weren't written within the Rails core setup, which is kinda the point. Every mainstream RDBMS is supported by someone (even Sybase) and there are heaps of NoSQL options too. Google "Activerecord adapter" to get a taste of the range available - it's huge.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I fear I may have been unclear: AR doesn't explicitly support prepared statements at all. Where a DB platform implements them, you may be able to access the functionality via ActiveRecord::Base#execute or similar. Of course, you could always fork the adapter and add support yourself...

Comment: I meant there were 3 on the link I put there. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 3.1 (or greater) supports prepared statements. Every new query you make will be added to pool of prepared statement. If you are are using MySql DB it still won't support prepared statement because using prepared statements in MySql reduces the performance compare to without prepared statement. [Here](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/10/22/show-some-love-for-prepared-statements-in-rails-3-1) is the nice article by [Pat Shaughnessy](http://patshaughnessy.net/) on this.

Answer (score 2):

In many (most?) ways, a DB View is a prepared statement. And it is easy to use views with ActiveRecord. Just declare the view in your DB (I use rake tasks) and then access it via ActiveRecord.

Works great for read-only access to complicated SQL. Saves the DB from many of the steps required to parse/compute SQL.